# python azure sdk - To list storage account SKU

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, sdk

I am using Python3 SDK for azure.
Here is version details of all the modules currently installed.
I want to list the Storage Account Types/SKU using SDK. Not sure how to do it.

```
azure-common (1.1.26)
azure-core (1.10.0)
azure-identity (1.5.0)
azure-keyvault-secrets (4.2.0)
azure-mgmt-compute (18.2.0)
azure-mgmt-core (1.2.2)
azure-mgmt-resource (15.0.0)
azure-mgmt-storage (16.0.0)
azure-storage-blob (12.7.1)
msrestazure (0.6.4)
```

[Here is official link from Azure.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/srp_sku_types)But I want to list this information via code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `azure-mgmt-storage==16.0.0`, there is a [`list()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-storage/azure.mgmt.storage.v2019_06_01.operations.skusoperations?view=azure-python#list---kwargs-) method in the `SkuOperations` class. Since the method will return multiple skus for every region and storage kind available, you can use a set to remove duplicate SKU names.

```py
from azure.mgmt.storage import StorageManagementClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

storage_client = StorageManagementClient(
    credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
    subscription_id="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
)

skus = {sku.name for sku in storage_client.skus.list()}

print(skus)
```

Which outputs the following set:

```py
{'Standard_GZRS', 'Standard_GRS', 'Standard_ZRS', 'Standard_RAGZRS', 'Premium_LRS', 'Premium_ZRS', 'Standard_LRS', 'Standard_RAGRS'}
```

If you simply want to list these skus, then you can iterate the set:

```py
for sku in skus:
    print(sku)
```

Which outputs the SKUs on newlines like so:

```py
Premium_LRS
Standard_GRS
Standard_GZRS
Premium_ZRS
Standard_LRS
Standard_RAGRS
Standard_RAGZRS
Standard_ZRS
```